# What is the source of gravitational force

Tags: gravity

What is the source of gravitational force ? Will it work between two charged particle ?

Comment: Well, if electron attracted to proton then it might be attracted to neighbor atom's protons as well. Hardly there is some other gravitational force. G is just a calculation approximation.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, gravity works between charged particles -- but is about ${10}^{40}$ times weaker than the electrostatic force between two electrons.  This means that it would be extremely difficult to measure it directly.

This site goes over the calculations in detail: http://www.batesville.k12.in.us/physics/phynet/e%26m/electrostatics/michaels_question.htm

Comment: I pedantically challenge that we "cannot" measure it directly. A positron and electron will have a higher net acceleration toward each other than two positrons will have away from each other, which is directly measurable with a suitable instrument. Now, designing and building a suitable instrument may be practically impossible, but I don't think it's principally impossible. Anyway, +1 for concisely addressing the issue.

Comment: @Asher: I agree with your comment, and will revise the answer.  Note that positronium an be subjected to very precise resonance experiments, but electron-electron repulsion is not going to be very difficult to measure, and would not be anywhere near as precise via any direct measurement that I can think of.  Perhaps a review of the King experiments (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_G._King_(physicist)) would suggest something clever!